# Using roscpp in external software

Tags: ros, gui, roscpp, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to link to roscpp in an external software such to communicate with the ROS system running on my robot.

The scope is to use my Qt5 GUI to control and configure the robot on different systems (Windows, Linux, Android...).

Is there a guide or examples about this process?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192388/using-roscpp-in-external-software/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might also want to look into [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) and write a plugin for it to implement your specific UI.

One of the advantages is that your tool can then be used together with other plugins in a unified interface.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2014-09-12**:
Hi Dirk,
I knew about rqt, is it yet based on Qt4.8?

However I do not think that I can use rqt on different platforms... what I'm searching for is a way to "subscribe" and to "publish" in a "not rosnode", nominally to insert a "node" inside a pre-existing application.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-17**:
rqt supports PyQt as well as PySide. For the second one only Qt 4.x support is available.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-17**:
The C++ client library of ROS is structured in a way that it allows it to be used easily within any other code. Just use the API as described in the normal tutorials.